# Emacs: change Ido completion keymap in minibuffer

Tags: emacs, elisp, ido

I use Ido mode and also use Ergoemacs mode, which binds `find-file` command to <kbd>C-o</kbd>. When you are browsing files, you can temporarily disable Ido by pressing <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd> inside minibuffer. I want to change it to <kbd>C-o</kbd>, so i can press it twice to run `find-file` without Ido. How can i do that?

In `ido.el` i see that Ido uses function `ido-init-completion-maps`, where it defines keys by running code like

```
(let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
  (define-key map "\C-x\C-f" 'ido-fallback-command))
```

However i'm not sure how to use this to bind `ido-fallback-command` to <kbd>C-o</kbd> inside minibuffer.

Emacs version: 24.0.94.1

**Edit (20.03.12)**: After discussion with [Francesco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1225607/francesco) i evaluated: `(define-key ido-file-completion-map "\C-o" 'ido-fallback-command)`.

Now when i press <kbd>C-h k C-o</kbd> i see this line: `C-o Fallback to non-ido version of current command`.

However when i press <kbd>C-o</kbd> again in minibuffer, i get this error: `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Command attempted to use minibuffer while in minibuffer")` <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd> in minibuffer still worked as fallback command.

We found out that Ergoemacs package has to do with it. When i turn off Ergoemacs-mode, both <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd> and <kbd>C-o</kbd> work as fallback commands. I tried to swap Ido and Ergoemacs keymaps in `minor-mode-map-alist` using the following code:

```
(let ((elem (first
         (remove-if-not
          '(lambda (item) (equal 'ido-mode (car item)))
          minor-mode-map-alist))))
  (setq minor-mode-map-alist (remove elem minor-mode-map-alist))
  (add-to-list 'minor-mode-map-alist elem))

(define-key ido-file-completion-map "\C-o" 'ido-fallback-command)'
```

Didn't work.

Answer (score 6):

You can use something like this:

```
(define-key ido-file-completion-map "\C-o" 'ido-fallback-command)
```

Comment: I have tried this in order to set `C-o` to disable by setting it to `nil`, which did not work